# Rails 3 Routing How to Match the Action in the Query String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, query-string

I am trying to match the following URL:

```
http://www.example.org/wiki/some/long/path?action=edit
```

Where "some/long/path" is the :path param

I have been using

```
match '/wiki/*path/action=:action' => 'wiki#show', :as => :wiki_path
```

but, with this method I can't match http://www.example.org/wiki/some/long/path and get the show action.

Any advice is appreciated :D

Comment: No errors, just not able to put together a match pattern that would  recognize the action in the query string; match '/wiki/*path?action=:action' doesn't seem to affect the action

Comment: Is this url set in stone? You're having trouble because Rails isn't designed to route via querystrings.

Comment: I am open to suggestions ;) the gotcha seems to be that the path has forward slashes in them, that is set in very firm cheese

Comment: `action` is reserved, you are better off using a different query parameter.